Have classical scholars of Sunni Islam allowed a husband to force his wife into intimacy if she's rejecting without a valid reasons
Have classical scholars of Sunni Islam allowed a husband to force his wife into intimacy if she's rejecting without a valid reason (as long as he's gentle and allows her to get herself aroused first so it doesn't hert her).
Among modern day scholars, I've seen those who denounce marital rape as a barbaric atrocity and those who consider it disliked but not a sin.
So I'ld really appreciate fatwas of CLASSICAL SCHOLARS along with supporting textual evidences from Quran and Sunnah (or something else like sahabi's fatwa) with full Arabic Sanad and Matn quoted.

It would be better if you added your personal take on this as an answer rather than including it within the question. Also kindly refrain from adding comments that cause disputes.
